# i18n not working with spring mvc and tiles support

Tags: spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="in.controllers" />

            <context:annotation-config />

            <!-- This tag adds DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping. If <mvc:resources /> 
                is tag is used, it will add the ResourceHttpRequestHandler, which will break 
                the existing default handlers added by the spring. So it is required to add 
                the handler mapping explicitly or add <mvc:annotation-driven /> tag. -->
            <mvc:annotation-driven />

            <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" />

            <!-- <bean id="viewNameTranslator" -->
            <!-- class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator" 
                /> -->

        <!--        If you do not register any “localeResolver”, the default AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver will be used,  -->
        <!--        which resolves the locale by checking the accept-language header in the HTTP request. -->

            <bean id="multipartResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

            <bean id="viewResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <!--        <property name="order" value="0" /> -->
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
                <property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
            </bean>
            <!-- for bilingual ..these are the settings ....starts... -->

            <bean id="messageSource"
                class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
                <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="locale"></property>
            </bean>

            <bean id="localeResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
                <property name="defaultLocale" value="kan"></property>
            </bean>

            <!-- the “order” property, where the lower order value has the higher priority. -->
            <bean id="handlerMapping"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <!--        <property name="order" value="1" /> -->
                <property name="interceptors">
                    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"></ref>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <!-- for bilingual ..these are the settings ....ends... -->
        </beans>
```

..

The above is my spring-servlet xml file.. using this in  my jsp

```
<a href="?locale=en">English</a> <a href="?locale=kan">
```

i18n not working ..please help..and all the messages properties files are present..but still i18n is not working..please help..

Comment: Remove the `handlerMapping` it breaks stuff. You are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` then use `<mvc:interceptors />` to register interceptors.

Comment: your suggestion solved the issue..... thank u veryyy muchhhh  @M. Deinum...you saved my day..thank u so much...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the your block code:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
           <property name="paramName" value="locale"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="kan"></property>
</bean>
<!-- the “order” property, where the lower order value has the higher priority. -->
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <!--        <property name="order" value="1" /> -->
    <property name="interceptors">
         <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"></ref>
    </property>
</bean>
```

By using following code:

```
<!-- Define locale resolver -->
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
        p:defaultLocale="kan" p:cookieName="languageSession" />
<!-- Register the interceptors -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="locale"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```